# How to make generic class inherit methods from other generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, architecture, polymorphism

I have two base classes:

```
DataLogic<T>
{
    protected abstract IEnumerable<string> Validate(T o);

    protected virtual bool Editable(T o)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected virtual bool Viewable(T o)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

ImportLogic<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Import(Stream importFileStream)
    {
        ...
        IEnumerable<T> importedObjects;
        ...
        foreach (var importedObject in importedObjects)
        {
             ...
             // HERE I WANT TO REACH METHOD FROM DATA LOGIC
             var validationResult=Validate(importedObject);
             ...
        }
        ...
    }

    protected abstract bool IsStructureValid(Worksheet sheetToValidate);
}
```

Data logic handles all data operations like data validation. So I can have class like `CarLogc : DataLogic<Car>` that handles business logic for `Car` objects.

Import logic handles operations like handling files. So if I want to make import of car list.

Now,  I want to have validation method of car object only in one place, and that should be in `DataLogic` (f.e. `CarLogic` for Cars).

But if I create `CarImportLogic` class, that inherits from `ImportLogic<Car>` I can't inherit also from `CarLogic`.

One solution I came up with is to give ImportLogic containng DataLogic property, but I don't like it, because it makes code much more unclear and I need to make data methods public.

So, how can I achieve these goals:

- Have generic classes for different business objects.
- Have validation logic in only one place.
- Can reach validation logic from ImportLogic   class.
- Keep my code elegant and easy to develop.

Comment: I think you want composition instead of inheritance, so your solution is not bad. Similar approach would be to create another class that wraps both your Data and Import logic together, like a decorator.

Comment: @CrudaLilium I wrote about hits in my question, with composition I loose clarity and flexibility of current code. If you can provide any working solution of wraping both logics together please do

Answer (score 0):

So I initially misunderstood your question, so let me point out few things, maybe they are what you need.
From the code you provided one can see that both your logic classes has to be abstract. In which case DataLogic class is useless as abstraction since it has no public methods. ImportLogic has dependency on DataLogic.Validate, but you need to make it public first. Next it seems you want to make one class that wraps both functionality, in this case it would be better to make your Logic classes as interfaces and make one abstract class with default functionality.

```
    interface IValidate<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<string> Validate(T objectToValidate);
    }

    interface IImport<T>
    {
        IEnumerable<string> Import(Stream importFileStream);
    }

    abstract class LogicWrapper<T> : IValidate<T>, IImport<T>
    {
        protected virtual bool Editable(T o)
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected virtual bool Viewable(T o)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public abstract IEnumerable<string> Validate(T objectToValidate);

        public IEnumerable<string> Import(Stream importFileStream)
        {
            return this.Validate(default(T));
        }
    }

    class CarLogic : LogicWrapper<Car>
    {
        public override IEnumerable<string> Validate(Car objectToValidate)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

It's hard to tell if this is what you are looking for, or is the right class structure since I don't know how you plan to use the `CarLogic` class next. If you want to keep your code elegant and easy to develop, just follow SOLID principles and you will be fine.